# Start->Run vs CMD

Tags: windows, command-line

So I have this application installed on my computer that have independently added sort of a prefix to allow IE/Any browser to link directly to that app.

For example:

```
appname://open/555890405
```

Will launch the application and do some stuff with the ID at the end of the string

So if I place that bit in Start->Run, it works. It successfuly launches the app. But if I paste the same string in cmd.exe window it fails to launch.

Comment: These "prefixes" (`http:`, `ftp:`, `appname:`) are called [URI schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

Comment: @grawity Thanks! did not know that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prefix it with `start` when you use it in `cmd.exe`, i.e. `start http://www.google.com`, `start appname://open/555890405`.

`cmd.exe` expects the first space-delimited token you enter to be an internal command, drive letter specification, or filename - not a URL.  But the `start` command supports that.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is there any way of running that uri scheme directly through an AutoIt script? I have the Run() function, but even if I place ``start appname://open/555890405`` in it it doesn't work. I guess it's expecting to get a filename for an application.

Comment: try `cmd /c "start appname://open/555890405"`

Comment: @OrW: Use [ShellExecute](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm) -- the same function as used by the *Start - Run* dialog.